# xcode: is there a way to import data/schema into the xcdatamodel file/directory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Is there a way to import existing data or schema into the xcdatamodel in xcode?

If not, is it possible to programmically write the xcdatamodel?

I was thinking if it is possible to create the xcdatamodel programmically then I can write a utility that can generate the xcdatamodel from a give .sql file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples of this. [Marcus's book](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data) on Core Data has a great example and there's probably no one outside of 1 Infinite Loop that knows more about Core Data than Marcus. There's also a bit in the Core Data programming guide about importing data [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html).